Time series windowing approach

I have this problem statement from my project is that base on the 5 mins data to predict the next 2 minutes. (you can look at the top) each segment of 5 minutes predict the next 2 minutes.
However, is there another way to approach this problem ? Because in real life we want to achieve is that after 5 minutes we would want to predict the next 2 min constantly on the 8th, 9th and so on.
How would the software engineering approach be for this segmenting ?
Something like this 2nd picture


This has nothing to do with forecasting then, you need to run a job every minute, taking data from the last 5 minutes and forecasting the next 2 minutes. Are you asking how to set up a job running every minute?

yes correct, how my script would look like ?
1 to 5 mins predict 6 & 7 mins.    3  to 7 mins predict 8 & 9 mins.    5 to 9 mins predict 10 & 11 mins.

so for first 5 mins is the baseline , the key is to constant predict the next 2 mins after the first 5 minutes
